# Some simple advice on understanding and using web services?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, ups

I do not know why it is so hard to find anything online walking me through what I'm about to ask, but I can't, so here it is:

I have read all about web services.  I know what they are and the point of them, but I cannot find any super helpful documentation on HOW they are used from the basic start.

My case in point:  I need to integrate UPS and FedEx package tracking into my software.  Just a simple "Enter tracking number:", then display all relevant tracking information.  Simple enough.  Except I discovered the only real way to do this is using their respective web services.  I am perfectly fine with that, except that I cannot find any real documentation on how to start using this "web service"

Starting with UPS, I downloaded their API/SDK.  It consisted of some documentation, some code examples, one .wsdl schema, and several .xsd schemas.  These I recognize as XML, and can see the structure they're trying to portray.  However, I have no idea how to use these in Eclipse to replicate the code samples shown.  The code samples are accessing an actual imported API (com.ups.blah.blah.blah), and then using the objects like TrackRequest, but there is no documentation on the "in-between" part... in other words, how do I get to this point given these wsdl and xsd files?

Could someone please give me, or point me to, a crash course on this pivotal part that I cannot seem to find guidance on anywhere?  (I am a noob when it comes to dealing with web services, so please forgive my ignorance)

Comment: Based on your description of the API, I'm guessing the API classes handle the actual http request that asks for data from the ups server.  If that's the case,  all you need to do is use these classes,  as shown in the examples, in an application running on a computer connected to the internet.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right; however, this does not really tell me how to get to that point to use these classes.  Their SDK does not include these actual classes.  They simply have the wsdl and xsd files mentioned above.  This is also so their web service can be language agnostic, but I do not know how to access these classes to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSDL will describe which service(s) exist at a given endpoint. A service is basically a method call. The input & output of the service are described by the XSD files (xml schema) which allow for both a universal data representation and validation of said data.

The JDK ships with a tool called `wsimport`, it will generate all the necessary classes based on a WSDL. I would suggest adding `-keep` as an option when you run it, otherwise you will only have the compiled version of the classes.

Using these classes it is trivial to construct a request and call the endpoint.

**UPDATE**

Also in the WSDL is the description of the endpoint: so the actual http location that the service should be called at. This is also parsed by wsimport and unless you override it, it will be used to call the service.

Note that `wsimport` generates classes on your **local** machine that you should treat as any other java dependency. The classes contain all the necessary logic to construct an input, perform the request and parse the output. It should be almost entirely transparent to you that it is actually a webservice call instead of a local method.

Comment: So from my understanding, when I make my own classes to handle the retrieval of tracking information, the API methods I use will somehow be directed to use the method implementation on UPS's server, for instance.  So, I won't have to actually have those classes built locally when I deploy my UPS tracker?  How do I point my java code to use these services?  Is the wsimport tool simply to build the classes locally for testing while implementing?